# Access To ServiceBus.Messaging.EventData in an Azure Function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I'd like to create an Azure Function that fires whenever a message is sent to an Azure IoT hub. In a C# app I wrote, I create a method that pulls messages off the hub. In that method I have access to the ServiceBus.Messaging.EventData object that contains all available information about a message. The method looks as follows:

```
   private static async Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(string partition, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().CreateReceiver(partition, System.DateTime.UtcNow);

        while (true)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            EventData eventData = await eventHubReceiver.ReceiveAsync();
            if (eventData == null)
                continue;

            // Get the Device Id which is included in the SystemProperties dictionary
            string deviceId = eventData.SystemProperties["iothub-connection-device-id"].ToString();

            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());
            Console.WriteLine("Message received - DeviceId: {0}; Partition: {1}; Data: '{2}'", deviceId, partition, data);
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to create a C# based Azure Function in the portal, the default method created looks as follows:

```
public static void Run(string myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {myIoTHubMessage}");
}
```

I was wondering if there was someway I could get access to the entire message object, like I can in my C# app, as opposed to just the message itself ('myIotHubMessage')?

Note: I tried the following but Azure Functions didn't like the first using reference. It couldn't find the reference.

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using System.Text;

public static void Run(EventData eventData, TraceWriter log)
{
    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

    log.Info($"C# IoT Hub trigger function processed a message: {data}");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just replace `string` with `EventData`, add reference to the package and `using` for the namespace:

```cs
#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

public static void Run(EventData myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myEventHubMessage.GetBytes())}");
}
```

Comment: I actually tried that but got an error that said my using reference could not be found. This is what I added: using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;

Comment: @RandyMinder Extended my answer with full example

Comment: Thank you Mikhail, but this isn't working either, although I'm getting a different error. The error is: [Error] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.MonitorIoTHub'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 
 Cannot bind parameter 'myEventHubMessage' to type EventData. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. 
 If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).

Comment: @RandyMinder Are you routing your IoT events to Event Hub or Service Bus? Which trigger type does your function have?

Comment: All messages are flowing into an IoT hub and the trigger was created based on an event hub.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the next steps to create an Azure Function that fires whenever a message is sent to an Azure IoT hub.

1. Create an IoT hub using the Azure portal, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal).
2. Create Function Apps, and add a function for IoTHub, this function will be run whenever an IoT Hub delivers a new message for Event Hub-compatible endpoints. 
   [image]
3. Modify the code in your function as following, save and run the function.

> ```
> #r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"
> using System.Text;
> using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
>
> public static void Run(EventData myIoTHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
> {
>     log.Info($"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myIoTHubMessage.GetBytes())}");
> }
> ```

When you use a device client send messages to IoT Hub, the function app will fire, it will show in the logs.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what '#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"' does, and why it's not necessary for the other using statement?

Comment: @RandyMinder , `'#r "Microsoft.ServiceBus"'` means it need to add reference of external assemblies. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies).